# Is there any smart trick to locate Keymap names belonging to specific identifiers?

Tags: customization, keymap

I don't know if I've phrased my question right, but I always find it super hard to locate the actual location of keymaps in situations where I know (and see) the operator/identifier in the Key-Binding menu. Eg. when I want to duplicate that key and bind two keymaps to the operator.

Maybe these screenshots explain better what my question is about:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you export the keymap (into a keymap.py) file and search with a text editor, you can probably figure out the hierarchy from there.